# How do we find two most-weighted routes in a grid?

Tags: c, algorithm, matrix, routes, dynamic-programming

> We a given a weighted  N*N grid W. Two robots r1,r2 start from top left and top right corners respectively. R1 has to reach to the bottom right and R2 the bottom left corners. Here are the valid moves.
>
> - R1 moves one square down, R2 moves one square left.
> - R1 moves one square right, R2 moves one square down.
>
> They must move in such a way that the sum of the weights of the squares they visit (including the starting and ending square) is maximized.
>
> For Examples, if the grid is:
>
> ```
> 6   0   3   1
> 7   4   2   4
> 3   3   2   8
> 13  10  1   4
> ```
>
> In this example, if R1 follows the path marked by * and R2 follows the path marked
>   by ^, as shown below, their combined score is 56.
>
> ```
>  6*   0     3^   -1^
>  7*   4*^   2^    4
> -3    3*^  -2*    8*
>  13^  10^  -1    -4*
> ```
>
> It can be verifyed that this is the best combined score that can be achieved for this grid.

We cannot solve this by recursion as N <= 2500 and the time limit is 2 seconds.
If the problem had only one robot, we could solve this by using dynamic programming.

I tried using a similar approach for this problem;

We have two extra N*N grids G1,G2,

```
for i from 1 to N:
   for j from 1 to N and K from N down to 1:  
     if (G1[i-1][j] + G2[i][k+1]) > (G1[i][j-1] + G2[i-1][k]):
        G1[i][j] = G1[i-1][j] + W[i][j]
        G2[i][k] = G2[i][k+1] + W[i][k]
     else:
        G1[i][j] = G1[i][j-1] + W[i][j]
        G2[i][k] = G2[i-1][k] + W[i][k]

return G1[N][N] + G2[N][1]
```

but this gives a wrong answer. 
I am not able to understand what is wrong with my algorithm, because for each square it is calculating the max weighted path to rech there.

Can anyone tell me what is wrong with my method and how can i correct it to get the correct answer?

Comment: Did you try the [dijkstra algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm)?

Comment: @rekire I dont think this is a graph problem, but a dynamic programming problem, because it is a weighted grid rather than an adjacency matrix dijkstra's algorithm wont be suitable for this.

Comment: Try weighted BFS if you specifically want a graph algo

Comment: If I guess right, then you just need to invert the metric and that should run fine. But I'll read you question a second time.

Comment: @AshRj I dont want a graph algo, but a dynamic programming algo, also the routes of the two robots depend on each other

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**It is a graph problem**, and the graph is `G=(V,E)` where:

- V = Squares x Squares (The [Cartesian product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product) of all the squares)

  (You might want to exclude points where (x1,y1)=(x2,y2), it can be easily done).
- E =  { all possible ways to move in a turn } = (or formally) = 

  { (((x1,y1),(x2,y2)),((x1-1,y1),(x1,y1-1))), (((x1,y1),(x2,y2)),((x1,y1-1),(x1-1,y1))) | per x1,y1,x2,y2 }

Now, once we have the graph - we can see it is actually a **[DAG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_acyclic_graph)** - and this is a good thing, because for a general case graph - the [longest path problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_path_problem) is [NP-Hard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP-hard), but not for DAG.

Now, given a DAG `G`, we want to find the longest path from `((0,0),(n,n))` to `((n,n),(0,0))`, and it can be done with the following approach:

For simplicity define `weight((x1,y1),(x2,y2)) = weight(x1,y1) + weight(x2,y2)`:

**The algorithm:**

1. Use [topological sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting) on the graph
2. Init D((n,n),(0,0)) = weight((n,n),(0,0)) (the target node)
3. Iterate the graph according to the sort descending and do for each vertex `v`:
    
   D(v) = max { D(u) | for each (v,u) in E as described above } + weight(v)

When you are done D((0,0),(n,n)) will have the optimal result.

Comment: "Now, given a DAG G, we want to find the longest path from ((0,0),(n,n)) to ((n,n),(0,0))" We actually want to find the longest path from ((0,0)(0,N) to ((N,N)(N,0))). And there are restrictions on how we can move, the moves will always be together

Comment: @A.06: It doesn't really matter what's the start and target is - just change those, the same applies. Note that in the graph we built - the steps are indeed taken always together, if one robots moves - the other one moves to his valid direction as well.

Answer (score 1):

I could see a typo in the 2nd valid scenario

The valid 2nd scenario should be

> ***R1*** moves one square right, R2 moves one square down

but was given as

> ***R2*** moves one square right, R2 moves one square down